# angular injectable.providedIn vs module.providers

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-providers, angular-decorator

A Common practice is to include services in `@NgModule.providers`

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MessageService
  ]
})
```

According to [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#provide-the-heroservice), you can provide a service without specifying it in the `@NgModule` decorator, by using `@injectable.providedIn`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {...}
```

Is there any advantage for using the method presented in the Angular tutorial?